# Correlate Source with Assembly Listing of a C++ Program

Tags: c++, c, linux, gdb, objdump

Analyzing Core Dump in retail build often requires to correlate the `objdump` of any specific module and the source. Normally correlating the assembly dump with the source becomes a pain if the function is quite involved. 
Today I tried to create an `assembly listing` of one particular module (with the compile option `-S`) expecting I would see an interleaving source with assembly or some correlation. Unfortunately the listing was not friendly enough to correlate so I was wondering

- Given a core-dump from which I can determine the crash location
- `objdump` of the failing module Assembly Listing by recompiling the
- module with `-S` option.

Is it possible to do a one-to-one correspondence with the source?

As an example I see the assembly listing as

```
.LBE7923:
        .loc 2 4863 0
        movq    %rdi, %r14
        movl    %esi, %r12d
        movl    696(%rsp), %r15d
        movq    704(%rsp), %rbp
.LBB7924:
        .loc 2 4880 0
        testq   %rdx, %rdx
        je      .L2680
.LVL2123:
        testl   %ecx, %ecx
        jle     .L2680
        movslq  %ecx,%rax
        .loc 2 4882 0
        testl   %r15d, %r15d
        .loc 2 4880 0
        leaq    (%rax,%rax,4), %rax
        leaq    -40(%rdx,%rax,8), %rdx
        movq    %rdx, 64(%rsp)
```

but could not understand how to interpret the labels like `.LVL2123` and directives like `.loc 2 4863 0`

**Note**
As the answers depicted, reading through the assembly source and intuitively determining pattern based on symbols (like function calls, branches, return statement) is what I generally do. I am not denying that it doesn't work but when a function is quite involved, reading though pages of Assembly Listing is a pain and often you end up with listing that seldom match either because of functions getting in-lined or optimizer have simply tossed the code as it pleased. I have a feeling seeing how efficiently `Valgrind` handles optimized binaries and how in Windows WinDBG can handled optimized binaries, there is something I am missing. So I though I would start with the compiler output and use it to correlate. If my compiler is responsible for mangling the binary it would be the best person to say how to correlate with the source, but unfortunately that was least helpful and the `.loc` is really misleading. 
Unfortunately I often have to read through unreproducible dumps across various platforms and the least time I spend is in debugging Windows Mini-dumps though WinDBG and considerable time in debugging Linux Coredumps. I though that may be I am not doing things correctly so I came up with this question.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question but might be useful anyway: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238730%28v=vs.60%29.aspx

Comment: The core dump should have addresses in it. So try the `addr2line` program to translate into source locations. This is of course requires an executable with debug symbols (it should work even if your distributed version was stripped, just compare to a non-stripped version)

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: I will try this and let you know where I end with. BTW, shouldn;t this be an answer rather than a comment?

Comment: @Abhijit, I was unclear if this is exactly what you are seeking. I've also not done this exact scenario, so I can't be certain it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to do a one-to-one correspondence with the source?

A: no, unless all optimisation is disabled.
The compiler may emit some group of instructions (or instruction-like things) per line initially, but the optimiser then reorders, splits, fuses and generally changes them completely.

---

If I'm disassembling release code, I look at the instructions which should have a clear logical relationship to the code. Eg,

```
.LBB7924:
        .loc 2 4880 0
        testq   %rdx, %rdx
        je      .L2680
```

looks like a branch if `%rdx` is zero, and it comes from line 4880. Find the line, identify the variable being tested, make a note that it's currently assigned to `%rdx`.

```
.LVL2123:
        testl   %ecx, %ecx
        jle     .L2680
```

OK, so this test and branch has the same target, so whatever comes next knows `%rdx` and `%ecx` are both nonzero. The original code might be structured like:

```
if (a && b) {
```

or perhaps it was:

```
if (!a || !b) {
```

and the optimiser reordered the two branches ...

Now you've got some structure you can hopefully match to the original code, you can also figure out the register assignments.  Eg, if you know the thing being tested is the data member of some structure, read backwards to see where `%rdx` was loaded from memory: was it loaded from a fixed offset to some other register? If so, that register is probably the object address.

Good luck!

Comment: +1 for the detail tutorial. Its really wonderful. But unfortunately this and mostly what @Chris has mentioned is what I do to read through the dump. But you would agree, reading through pages of dumps may sometimes becomes a real pain and above all when function gets in-lined. For ex, today I almost spend an hour to read almost 1000 lines of assembly. I had a hunch that there should be something I am missing considering how efficiently and almost predictably `Valgrind` maps a fully optimized binary with the source listing if you compile with `-g` option (with symbols).

Comment: Well, the `.loc` label can map a group of instructions to a line of code, and presumably valgrind can use that to attribute approximate instruction cost to a source line. However, that is not the same as figuring out why a program crashed: you're trying to reconstruct the _logical_ program state which the optimiser transformed and discarded.  That's harder, and is not required for valgrind accounting.

Answer (score 4):

The `.loc` directive is what you're looking for. These indicate line #4863, 4880, etc. There is no perfect mapping between source and optimized assembler (which is why you see 4880 more than once). But `.loc` is how you know where it is in the file. The syntax is:

```
.loc <file> <line> <column>
```

Comment: Is their anything more I can infer here? For example the `.loc` has two other numbers like `2` and `0`. What are these? And what are these labels `.LVL2123` and `.LBE7923`?

Comment: Those are typically `goto` targets emitted by the compiler. For example you have `je      .L2680`, so there should be a line starting `.L2680:` somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you statically link against system libraries, even without debug symbols there will be symbolic names in the binary - that of the system library functions linked to.

These can often help narrow down where you are in the code.  For example, if you see that in function foo() it calls open() and then ioctl() and then it crashes right before calling read(), you can probably find that point in the source of foo quite easily. (For that matter you might not even need the dump - on linux you can get the record of crash occurrence relative to library and system functions using ltrace or strace)

Note that in some binary formats though, there may be an indirection to library functions via tiny wrappers elsewhere in the binary.  Often a dump will still have relevant symbolic name information at the address of the invocation in the program flow.  But even if not, you can recognize those external linkage wrappers by their range of address in the binary, and when you see one you can go find its code and figure out what external function it links to.

But as others have mentioned, if you have the source code and the system where it crashes frequently enough to be helpful, your fastest bet would usually be to rebuild with debug symbols, or insert logging output and get a more useful crash record.

Comment: Unfortunately I often have to debug unreproducible dumps across various systems and what you mentioned is the way I do and it works but I have to invest a lot of effort and time. I have estimated that debugging a Windows Mini-dump takes much less time (via WinDBG) compared to debugging a linux coredump. Even painful is debugging Solaris/AIX/HP-UX dumps. Seeing how efficiently Valgrind maps an optimized binary with source I got really ambitious and optimistic of determining something more efficient.  @edA-qa mort-ora-y had a suggestion that I am yet to try and let you know where I end with :-)